# How to do GroupBy and Rank in one sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have history table Date (datetime), Event (varchar), User (varchar), Text (varchar)

Event is a type of event (Exception, Request and so on) of history item, user is user identifier.
I want to choose specific event type ('Exception') and get the last Text (by Date) per each user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From SQL-Server 2005 on you can use a [CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) with [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT [Date], [Event], [User], [Text], 
          rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [User] ORDER BY [Date] DESC)
   FROM dbo.TableName
   WHERE [Event] = 'Exception'
)
SELECT [Date], [Event], [User], [Text]
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    T1.[Date],
    T1.Event,
    T1.[User],
    T1.Text
FROM (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY H.[User] ORDER BY H.[Date] DESC) AS ROW_NUM,
        H.[Date],
        H.Event,
        H.[User],
        H.Text
    FROM
        history H
    WHERE
        H.Event = 'Exception'
) AS T1
WHERE 
    T1.ROW_NUM = 1
```